# Netbackup, Backup Selections Missing From Backup

Tags: linux, netbackup

So I have a Linux server that is now gone, and that was being backed up by Netbackup 6.  When I go to restore, I don't see the folder listed.  I set the timeframe far back, and the policy to standard.  I do see some other folder like `/etc` and `/var`, but not `/export/tools` (What I am looking for).  This folder is listed as a backup selection for the policy that this server is under. I also see this folder backed up under other servers.

I don't think I added any exclusions, but since the client is gone, and `/opt/openv/..whatever` wasn't backed up, I don't think I can check that...?

Anything I can check to figure out why this might have not been backed up on the backup *server*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the */export* directory hosted via NFS?

If so, check your policy to see if you had the Follow NFS Mounts option checked in the policy attributes.  If the */exports* directory was mounted via NFS *AND* that option was not checked, then that policy may not have been backing up that directory.

Now, given the above, hopefully you were backing up the machine that the files were hosted on and they are available from there.

Otherwise, I am not sure that there is much you can do other than reviewing the logs for that client on the master server to see if it was processing that directory during backups.

Comment: That makes sense, but it should have been source of NFS the exports which is why I am confused.  I have the data backed up from a manual backup I did, but I am wonder why it isn't it netbackup.

Comment: Do you know if the logs on the server make a log entry for exclusions that were listed on the client?

Comment: Usually excluded backups will get an entry on the jobs activity slab, but will only be 32KB in size, or something similar. This is just the directory file/mount point being backed up, but not its contents.

If the /export directory is mounted via NFS and that Follow NFS mounts option is not checked in the policy, that is all it will do. You'll need to either check that option on the policy (which can be slow) or you need to be backing up that NFS server separately in another policy.

Answer (score 2):

I have no suggestions for you specifically. In general, if you haven't tested a restore, you're not doing backups properly. And always test a restore before you decommission a machine.